# DIV element has right margin even when set to 0 (like a display: block)

Tags: html, css

The div (the class is profile-preview-div) is taking up the whole margin like a block, even though its set as an inline block and the margin to 10 pixels, as shown in the picture: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZL5qb.png) on the chrome dev tools it shows as 10 px margin on all sides, but it still shows that right margin that takes up all the space for some reason.

```css
.profile-preview-div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 40% 40%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 40px);
  width: 200px;
  zoom: 2;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.pfp-div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 39px;
  margin: 0px;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

.pfp-preview {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}

.profile-p-name-div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  margin: auto;
}

.profile-p-name {
  margin: 0px;
}

.profile-p-desc {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 8px;
  color: grey;
}

.profile-p-desc-div {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  margin: auto;
}

.profile-p-stats-div {
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  width: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.profile-p-stats {
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: navy;
}

.profile-p-info {
  width: 80%;
}

#follow-button {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  width: 60%;
  height: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 8px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>
    Javascript idk
  </title>

  <script src="java.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="profile-preview-div">

    <div class="pfp-div">
      <img src="/pfps/pic1.png" class="pfp-preview">
    </div>



    <div class="profile-p-name-div">
      <p class="profile-p-name">asd_adventure</p>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-p-desc-div">
      <p class="profile-p-desc">i really like pizza lol</p>

    </div>

    <div class="profile-p-stats-div">
      <p class="profile-p-stats">Followers: 40</p>
      <p class="profile-p-stats">Following: 30</p>

    </div>

    <button id="follow-button">Follow</button>
  </div>



  <div class="profile-preview-div">

    <div class="pfp-div">
      <img src="/pfps/pic3.png" class="pfp-preview">
    </div>



    <div class="profile-p-name-div">
      <p class="profile-p-name">deego_washere_</p>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-p-desc-div">
      <p class="profile-p-desc">i really like pizza lol</p>

    </div>

    <div class="profile-p-stats-div">
      <p class="profile-p-stats">Followers: 40</p>
      <p class="profile-p-stats">Following: 30</p>

    </div>

    <button id="follow-button">Follow</button>
  </div>

  <script>
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

any help is appreciated, im new so i dont really know this behaviour. Ive seen other posts and none is helping, Because i dont have any justify-content elements in my css nor other things like those.

Comment: You have both `display: inline-block` and `display: grid` set up. Do you maybe mean `display: inline-grid`?

Comment: _"even though its set as an inline block"_ - it _isn't_. `display: inline-block` gets
overwritten by the `display: grid` you have in the same rule a couple of lines later.

Comment: Your .profile-preview-div is defined as a grid that's 200px wide with a background color of light blue. It looks about right.

Comment: @fatpenguin what do u mean?? is that satire lol

Comment: What I was saying is the browser rendered your div precisely as your CSS described...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your **.profile-preview-div** in css. You have **display: inline-block** and then you rewrite it with **display: grid**. If you remove it - your cards will position itself one beside another.

It looks like you want to create a grid inside each card to conveniently place elements inside, so if you want to preserve the grid, then remove that useles **display: inline-block**. Then you need to change the DOM structure of your page in way where you have additional wrapper around all cards like this:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="profile-preview-div"></div>
    <div class="profile-preview-div"></div>
</div>
```

Then in CSS:

```
.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

Hope this helps :)